# If $L,A \in m(n,n)$ on $R$, when exists L for which $(L^{T}AL)$ is a diagonal block matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $L,A \in m(n,n)$ on $R$, when exists L for which $(L^{T}AL)$ is a diagonal block matrix? Of course if $A$ is symmetrycal then $L$ exists and is a matrix of its eigenvectors, but I don't want to consider this case.

Comment: You are going to need a stronger condition to make this interesting, because every $n\times n$ matrix is a diagonal block matrix with one $n\times n$ block.

Comment: It was implicit that the numbers of blocks must be more than one. @Aaron